how to check how many users request handle on apache server ( ubuntu OS )
How can i calculate how many requests a server can handle
our server is 4vCPU, 16GB RAM and 300GB storage
How long does it take to process a single request on average?
What are the hardware and network limitations (CPU, RAM, Disk, Bandwidth)?
How many concurrent connections can the server handle based on available memory?
What is the nature of the traffic (static vs. dynamic content)?
What are the expected traffic patterns and peaks?
What is the impact of caching on server performance?
How efficient is the server’s interaction with the database or other back-end systems?

All the questions in the last part of your question has to be answered by you. The answer can be anything between one and thousands, depending on the workload.
